# Android Studio switches to local gradle distribution everytime I pull the project from git repo

Tags: git, gradle, android-studio-2.1

I work on my Android Studio 2.1.2 projects from two primary locations, at home, and at the company office. I us Git for the VCS.

Every time I pull the latest changes from the Git repo, the Android Studio Gradle Project-level settings get changed from *"Use default Gradle wrapper"* to *"Use local gradle distribution"*.

Why is this?

This means I have to dutifully set it back to *"Use default Gradle wrapper"* every time. I then do my work and commit my changes. But when I go to my other work location and pull those changes, Android Studio switches back to *"Use local gradle distribution"* again!!

Sure it's only a quick switch of a setting for me to fix it each time, but it's getting very irritating.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Do you have Gradle locally installed?  Does your Gradle file specify a wrapper?

Comment: @Makoto Yes there are local gradle distributions installed on both PCs, for use with a few legacy projects. But for most projects I want to use the default gradle wrapper.